# Unable to use react-native-voice package

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am trying to use react-native-voice package. In my project on button press I am calling Voice.start('en-US') method. But its showing the following error,

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection(id: 0):
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'Voice.startSpeech')
```

I have linked the package both automatically and manually. But it didn't worked

Side Notes: I ejected the project from expo managed workflow using expo eject

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [documentation](https://github.com/react-native-voice/voice) they have init Voice in constructor

**try this**

```
constructor(props) {
    Voice.onSpeechStart = this.onSpeechStartHandler.bind(this);
    Voice.onSpeechEnd = this.onSpeechEndHandler.bind(this);
    Voice.onSpeechResults = this.onSpeechResultsHandler.bind(this);  
 }   

onSpeechStartHandler = () => {}

 onSpeechEndHandler = () => {}

 onSpeechResultsHandler = () => {}

onStartButtonPress(e){
    Voice.start('en-US');   
}
```

also check the permissions

https://github.com/react-native-voice/voice#permissions

Comment: did you have check the https://github.com/react-native-voice/voice#permissions

Comment: But I am not getting the error for which audio record permission is required...That is why I did not Implemented that part.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue developing an react native app with react-native-voice package. I followed every step of the workflow, there seems nothing wrong.
`expo run:android` build successful. Then `expo start --dev-client` on my android emulator/physical device both throw this error:

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object
> (evaluating 'Voice.isSpeechAvailable')]

In the end, I found that, one needs to open two terminals in vscode, one terminal running `exp start` (while connecting to your device), and the other terminal simultaneously runs `expo run:android`.

The app then is running on the device like a charm!
Hope this helps, and hope someone can explain more on this regarding how react-native/expo test development works?